# Pixel 6 Pro Android emulator shows only the frame but not the screen

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device, android-api-30

I am building a flutter app and recently I updated Android studio to the Electric Eel version for the Pixel 6 & 6 Pro emulators. When I try to launch the Pixel 6 Pro emulator only the frame of the emulator is visible I cannot see the screen. This is how it looks
[image]

But when I take a screenshot from the emulator options I can see the screen in the screenshot.. The only issue is that the emulator is not displaying the UI.